# Significance of JMH annotation parameters

Tags: java, performance, benchmarking, microbenchmark, jmh

I'm running a benchmarking experiment making HTTP calls using JMH. However, there are couple of things that are not clear to me because the JMH Javadoc are like "here I document the annotation name for you without telling you what it does".

```
@Fork(value = 2, warmups = 1)
@Warmup(iterations = 1, time = 15)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 15)
@Threads(16)
public class BenchmarkRunner {
    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
    public void measureThroughput(Blackhole bh, MyHttpClient client) {
        bh.consume(client.exec());
    }
}
```

---

```
# Warmup: 1 iterations, 15 s each
# Measurement: 5 iterations, 15 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 16 threads, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Throughput, ops/time
# Benchmark: org.example.BenchmarkRunner.measureThroughput
```

Questions:

1. What is the significance of "5 iterations, **15 s each**"? Does it mean each iteration will run for 15 seconds within which JMH will make as many calls as possible?
2. What is the significance of "16 threads, **will synchronize iterations**"?

Comment: Are you asking about the internals? My assumption is that it performs some rudimentary operation that it can scale up to know how well the specific system it's running on is performing.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson I'm asking what do these statements mean. In other words, what does the `time` parameter do, and what does it mean to "synchronize iterations" across threads?

Comment: Have you reviewed something like this write-up? https://mkyong.com/java/java-jmh-benchmark-tutorial/
It gives an overview and a link to official samples and the source code to JMH as well.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson I've reviewed every article that came up in my Google searches. If you are able to point me to any that specifically answers my questions, please do. I'm done with articles that are merely copy-paste of each other. I've got very specific questions, and I'm hoping for specific answers, not vague and general links.

Comment: This official sample explains "will synchronize iterations": http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/2be2df7dbaf8/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_17_SyncIterations.java

Comment: I don't see where. The code you linked to uses that option without ever explaining what it does.

Comment: "The better solution would be to introduce bogus iterations..." - This is explaining what it does, and you can run the code and flip the flag to false to see the difference.

Comment: I'm afraid you're reaching. They are talking about ramp up and ramp down. Other software like JMeter does that too. But by all means, write your answer if you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250205/discussion-between-ryanwebjackson-and-abhijit-sarkar).

Answer (score 2):

I believe these questions to be general in nature. Any more detail would involve analyzing the source code, which is possible here: https://github.com/openjdk/jmh

> What is the significance of "5 iterations, 15 s each"? Does it mean
> each iteration will run for 15 seconds within which JMH will make as
> many calls as possible?

The Time parameter is used to limit the benchmark operation. The JMH tool will attempt to make as many operations ("calls") in that time as possible.

> What is the significance of "16 threads, will synchronize iterations"?

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/2be2df7dbaf8/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_17_SyncIterations.java
Per this official sample, "synchronize iterations" means that the threads spun up to operate on the benchmark run are all executing at the same time, thanks to warmup "bogus iterations".